# Android- org.apache.http.ProtocolException: The server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response

Tags: android, http, android-asynctask, apache-httpclient-4.x, rest-client

I am trying to send a HTTP post request to a REST service through my android app and the client runs as an async task. Here is the client:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    String address = "http://xxx.xx.x.xxx:8080/rest/manageUser/create";
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = null;
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters;
    try {
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(address);


        postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userId", userId));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstName", firstName));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastName", lastName));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobileNumber",
                mobileNumber));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("loginStatus",
                loginStatus));

        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        response = client.execute(httpPost);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream stream = entity.getContent();

        int b;
        while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
            stringBuilder.append((char) b);
        }

        // System.out.println(stringBuilder);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONObject jobj = null;

    try {
        jobj = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
        System.out.println(jobj.toString());
    } catch (Exception ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Also when I create the client as an standalone java class it works fine. But when I use it from my Android app as an async task as above, I get the following exception:

```
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
at com.example.hello.service.client.CreateUser.doInBackground(CreateUser.java:64)
at com.example.hello.service.client.CreateUser.doInBackground(CreateUser.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: The server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:93)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:180)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:428)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
... 10 more
 org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:155)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
at com.example.hello.service.client.CreateUser.doInBackground(CreateUser.java:82)
at com.example.hello.service.client.CreateUser.doInBackground(CreateUser.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Can anyone suggest what could be the problem. Also in my rest service, I am recieving the data with the @FormParam . Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using wrong HTTP method. Just check HTTP Method whether it is correct or not and just try to get json that is going as part of request body.